# I have 16.04 installed in sda7 which doesn't have enough room for new data. How do I expand it?

Tags: partitioning

The adjacent sda9 has enough room but I can't shrink it and expand sda7. How do I do that? Here's my gparted info.
[image]

Comment: you can expand using `gparted`, but currently your sda7 is mounted so it won't let you. with a lot of work you can umount your / drive, but its easier to boot your install media as a 'live' system, and then resize it using `gparted` there.  If you use `grub` and its info is stored in sda7 or 9 you may find it won't boot, so you may need some commands to continue boot (or use the live media again) to re-install the mbr (stage 1) of grub pointing to its new location (but this may not be necessary)

Comment: I do have Ubuntu 16 on an install USB key. I thought about this possibility but I'm a newbie and have been reluctant to reinstall it in  sda9. I'm not sure how to get it to boot from the "new" partition. I have backed up all my data and email from sda7 Could someone please outline the step by step process of "reinstalling" Ubuntu 16 on a "new" partition and then the grub edits suggested by guiverc which I might need to ensure my dual boot (Windows 7 (never used) and Ubuntu will work when starting up the computer.

Comment: boot your (ubuntu) install-key and select 'try-ubuntu' (*not install*!) which will let you use it in a 'live' environment, using none of your data/system partitions on hdd/sdd (it may still use swap; but this can be turned off). You can then re-size your partitions as they are not in use.  ((*in a 'live' environment all files exist in memory only; loaded from the booting thumb-drive or dvd; allowing you to boot another computer & use Ubuntu without any installation; eg. a borrowed computer*))

Comment: A belated thank you guiverc for your suggesstion. I "tried" ubuntu from my usb key and was able to repartition the drive and get enough space to work in properly. And I had no problems when I rebooted the system and didn't lose anything.